# Refine colormap for a surface plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
colorbar;
colormap hot;
x = colorbar;
caxis([-450,-100]);
x = set(x,'YTick',-450:25:-100);
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.Label.String='x';
ax.YAxis.Label.String='y';
set(gca,'YTick',[0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60]);
set(gca,'XTick',[0 5 10 15 20])
set(gcf,'Color','cyan');
```

I'm trying to refine the color on the surface shown below. How can I adjust the steps? Using `caxis([-450,-100])` makes the step linearly equal to `100`. How can I get a smooth color on the surface plot? I've been reading about it on the internet, but I couldn't do it, so I ask. Thank you.

[image: Refine color on surface with the colormap]

Comment: What do you mean by *smooth color*? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Set the Colormap Size
The size of the colormap determines how smooth the transition is between colors. A colormap with a small number of colors has sharp transitions between colors. A larger colormap provides much smoother transitions between colors. To change the number of colors in the colormap, pass an integer value to the built-in colormap.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/using-colormaps.html

Comment: This is NOT smooth:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab_featured/UsingColormapsExample_4.png

But this is smooth:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/examples/matlab_featured/UsingColormapsExample_5.png

Comment: So, what I actually meant by "smooth color" was: smooth transition between colors.

Comment: Where is the code to create the surface? most of the code you posted is not relevant to the problem (i.e. setting all the labels and ticks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some parameters that can help you to get a smoother plot:

- Number of colors in the colormap
- Number of surfaces
- How the surfaces are colored

This is a simple demonstration that shows how each parameter affect the generated plot:

```
f = @(mnp, n, facecolor){ subplot(mnp); ...
    surf(peaks(n), 'edgecolor', 'none', ...
    'facecolor', facecolor); view(2); ...
    title(sprintf('Grid: %d x %d, FaceColor: %s', n, n, facecolor)); ...
    colorbar};
f(221, 15, 'flat');
f(222, 15, 'interp');
f(223, 40, 'flat');
f(224, 40, 'interp');
colormap(jet(10))
figure
f(221, 15, 'flat');
f(222, 15, 'interp');
f(223, 40, 'flat');
f(224, 40, 'interp');
colormap(jet(100))
```

and this is the output:

[image]

### Number of Colors in the Colormap

You already know that:

> The size of the colormap determines how smooth the transition is between colors. A colormap with a small number of colors has sharp transitions between colors. A larger colormap provides much smoother transitions between colors.

But it probably doesn't make any changes in your case, so continue reading.

### Number of surfaces

As you can see in the sample code above, plots are drawn for two different numbers of surfaces. In first and third rows a grid of `15 by 15` surfaces are plotted, while in second and forth rows there are `40 by 40` surfaces ([more information about `peaks(n)`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/peaks.html?searchHighlight=peaks&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)). Seems like your data is a `5 by 13` matrix of values. Try to plot more surfaces, if you have a function that gives the value of z on each (x, y).

### How the surfaces are colored

You can see the difference between first and second columns. This is how [the `FaceColor` property](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitivesurface-properties.html) of a surface object changes how it looks.

> `'flat'` — Use uniform face colors. Use the `CData` values. The color data at the first vertex determines the color for the entire face.
>
> `'interp'` — Interpolate the face colors. Bilinear interpolation of the `CData` values at each vertex determines the colors.

### What if there was no function to generate more surfaces and linear interpolation of colors was not enough?

You can use [`interp2`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) function to generate more points. This is a sample:

```
% original data (7 by 7)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:3);
Z = peaks(X,Y);

% cubic interpolation of original data(61 by 61)
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(-3:.1:3);
ZI = interp2(X,Y,Z,XI,YI,'cubic');

% plot data (both original and interpolated)
subplot(121);
surf(X, Y, Z, 'edgecolor', 'none'); 
view(2);axis square
subplot(122);
surf(XI, YI, ZI, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', 'interp'); 
view(2);axis square
colormap(hot(300))
```

And the result:

[image]